# How do I specify the printer I want to use in Java?

Tags: java, printing

Currently retrieving the default printer installed on my machine for printing.  I want to be able to pick which printer the documents go to.  What is the best method of doing this ?

Code:

```
 PrintService[] services =
                PrintServiceLookup.lookupPrintServices(psInFormat, null);
        System.out.println("Printer Selected " + services[Printerinx]);

        //PrintService defaultService = PrintServiceLookup.lookupDefaultPrintService();

        DocFlavor[] docFalvor = services[Printerinx].getSupportedDocFlavors();
        for (int i = 0; i < docFalvor.length; i++) {
            System.out.println(docFalvor[i].getMimeType());
        }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Create the `PrintUtility` class below, import it and try calling `PrintUtility.findPrintService("name_of_my_printer");` if you know your printer name; if you don't know what printers you have access to, call `PrintUtility.getPrinterServiceNameList();` for a `List` containing all viable registered printer names.

Alternately see [my answer to this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11230502/printing-on-network-printer-which-is-not-installed-localy-in-java/11232987#11232987) for more details:

```java
package com.stackoverflow.print;

import java.awt.print.PrinterJob;
import javax.print.PrintService;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public final class PrintUtility {

    /**
     * Retrieve a Print Service with a name containing the specified PrinterName; will return null if not found.
     * 
     * @return
     */
    public static PrintService findPrintService(String printerName) {

        printerName = printerName.toLowerCase();

        PrintService service = null;

        // Get array of all print services
        PrintService[] services = PrinterJob.lookupPrintServices();

        // Retrieve a print service from the array
        for (int index = 0; service == null && index < services.length; index++) {

            if (services[index].getName().toLowerCase().indexOf(printerName) >= 0) {
                service = services[index];
            }
        }

        // Return the print service
        return service;
    }

    /**
     * Retrieves a List of Printer Service Names.
     * 
     * @return List
     */
    public static List<String> getPrinterServiceNameList() {

        // get list of all print services
        PrintService[] services = PrinterJob.lookupPrintServices();
        List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();

        for (int i = 0; i < services.length; i++) {
            list.add(services[i].getName());
        }

        return list;
    }

    /**
     * Utility class; no construction!
     */
     private PrintUtility() {}
}
```

Comment: yeah, your answer is correct! But what if the printer name is using '\\name of the printer' using that notion. Is it can be used ? or should we remove the double slash more as escaped character or something else?

Comment: @gumuruh The printer should be referenced as "\\name of the printer", however if you providing this value to your application as String data from a configuration file, double-check whether the "\\" needs to be properly escaped as "\\\\".  I currently have an application that references a printer in this same fashion and it works fine.  Make sure the value is used exactly as it appears in  the output from `getPrinterServiceNameList()` ; print out your String variable to log before you use it to ensure it is identical.

Comment: alright then.... it should be yes, thanks!

Answer (score 9):

The `PrintServiceLookup.lookupPrintService()` method provides a way to lookup a printer by name. Prepare a `HashAttributeSet` with a `PrinterName` attribute object and pass it to the lookup method.

Use code like below:

```
AttributeSet aset = new HashAttributeSet();
aset.add(new PrinterName("MyPrinter", null));
PrintService[] pservices = 
    PrintServiceLookup.lookupPrintServices(null, aset);
```

Works on Linux with CUPS.

Answer (score -1):

```
int i ;

DocFlavor fl= null;

PrintService printService[]= PrintServiceLookup.lookupPrintServices(fl,null); 

for(i=0;i<printService.length;i++)
{
    System.out.println(printService[i]);

}
```