# package sun.awt does not exist

Tags: java, intellij-idea, java-11, openjdk-11, adoptopenjdk

When compiling with `ant`, calls to `sun.awt.AppContext` work, however the same code compiled with IntelliJ fails using AdoptOpenJDK11.

- `sun.awt.AppContext` with **Oracle JDK8** works with IntelliJ
- `sun.awt.AppContext` with **AdoptOpenJDK11** does NOT work with IntelliJ

Although Sun/Oracle has [warned for a while](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/faq-sun-packages-142232.html) about avoiding the `sun.*` packages, there are [certain features (bugs?) in Java that still require them](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31054138/3196753) and stranger, the command line seems happy.

Sample code:

```
package test;

import javax.print.PrintService;
import javax.print.PrintServiceLookup;
import sun.awt.AppContext;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //Update printer list in CUPS immediately
        AppContext.getAppContext().put(PrintServiceLookup.class.getDeclaredClasses()[0], null);

        PrintService[] printers = PrintServiceLookup.lookupPrintServices(null, null);
        for (PrintService p : printers) {
            System.out.println(p.getName());
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

How does one configure IntelliJ to behave like `ant` and allow access to `sun.awt.*` packages?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Disable the **Use '--release' option...**:

[image: release]

[See this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49618223/104891) for details.

Comment: Thanks, that worked.  On Mac this was located in `IntelliJ IDEA > Preferences > Build, Execution, Deployment > Java Compiler`.

Comment: Thanks a lot, this was the issue for my project as well