# how to use printer in OS windows and my program in linux ubuntu

Tags: java, printing, epson

my program in server linux ubuntu and my printer in Windows
i want to print data from link and print in windows
i try to print with:

```
SMB:\\\\Ip printer\\Name printer
```

but it don't work
have solution?

my code is:

```
string1="test";
InputStream br = new ByteArrayInputStream(test.getBytes());
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(br));
String line;
FileWriter out = new FileWriter("SMB:\\\\IP printer\\name printer");
while((line = in.readLine()) != null)
{  
    System.out.println("line"+line);
    out.write(line);
    out.write(0x0D);  CR
    out.write('\n');
    writer.println(line);
}
out.close();
in.close();
```

my printer is EPSON TM-U295

Answer (score 0):

you should use [PrinterJob](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/print/PrinterJob.html)

This is what Java provides as API for such cases.
Here is a small code snippet to get you started:

```
PrinterJob printerJob = PrinterJob.getPrinterJob();
printerJob.setPrintable(new CustomPrintable("DATA TO PRINT"));
boolean printOK = printerJob.printDialog();
if (printOK){} 
    try {
        printerJob.print();
    }
    catch (PrinterException e){
        // Error
    }
}
```

I just realized I forgot to mention how to connect to you printer, here is a usefoul [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11230502/how-to-use-java-to-print-on-a-network-printer)

Comment: thanks for your answer, where I give the name of the printer?

Comment: `PrintService printService = PrintUtility.findPrintService(printerName);` works for me :). Check the link I have given you .

Comment: if my program in linux and my printer in windows?what inside (printerName)?if i use linux

Comment: You need to map the printer then. Do a google search about it.